# Parsing a log file help

Tags: perl, bash

I'm trying to write a either bash or perl script which runs twice a day that copies the last entry in a log and takes only the numbers and copies and replaces the value in a .dat file with those numbers. The format in the log is:

> (Event{id=275800).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -n 1 logfile.log | sed 's/.*id=\([^)]\+\).*/\1/' > file.dat
```

would be the bash command for it, as for twice a day a cronjob would be the easiest I think.

Comment: If I also wanted to make a backup of the original .dat file, would that be possible?

Comment: @jacob: you can figure out yourself how you copy/move an existing file, can't you?